# Customer, Prospects. Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We currently have table of prospects with related tables like communications and contacts etc. I'm trying to figure out the best design when that prospect becomes a customer. As I see it there are 2 options. One would be to have a Boolean field for prospect in that table. The other would be to insert that prospect into a customers table when they become a customer. I think both would work but I'm dreading that if I don't choose well I'm shooting myself in the foot in the future.

I should add that a customer has a lot more related tables than a prospect. Tables for invoices, dispatch etc.

Does anyone know which design would work better? Or is there a better option I'm not considering?

Comment: Like the bumper sticker says, strangers are simply friends you haven't met yet.

Comment: I think you should think about things like: How often a Prospect becomes a Customer? If is very often then you should simplify that task maybe having a userType field in which you set the type (prospect/customer). In terms of better database design my opinion is that having prospects and customers in different tables is more organized because when you try to convert a prospect into a customer, adding the invoices and dispatch records will be required by your model and that makes it more consistent. But I guess is up to you. Hope that helps

Comment: Along the lines of what @juanreyesv said... how are the attributes different for a prospect vs a customer? I would also lean towards having separate tables

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the boolean.  How hard would it be to create a customer table and migrate all prospects down the road?  Why add that overhead of multiple tables?  Now you'd have to check both tables potentially.. depending on your site's usage.

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE payingcustomer
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends whats is the diference on both models.

Some CRM system always manage the customer as a prospect. You can sell once to them but I guess you want sell something else later. So you keep always the contact data. If is that the case, I recomend you to manage customer like a prospect with a flag `is_customer` or whatever.

When prospect become to customer you can add related tables like invoices at the same time add dispatch to invoice and so on. But is still available for prospecting.

I hope this can help you!